# How do I find a HTML class name ending with blank space?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an HTML page:

```
<li id="user_432232" class="profile ">
  <section class="vcard clearfix">
    <div class="text">
      <div class="name">
      <h2 class="n fn">
        <a href="#" class="profile-link">Johww</a>
      </h2>

<div class="like-action like-action-user-432232">
  <div class="like" style=";">
    <span class="like-number" title="25 people like Jose">25</span>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
      <p class="title">SCR</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</li>
<li id="user_432232" class="profile ">
  <section class="vcard clearfix">
    <div class="text">
      <div class="name">
      <h2 class="n fn">
        <a href="#" class="profile-link">Jose </a>
      </h2>

<div class="like-action like-action-user-432232">
  <div class="like" style=";">
    <span class="like-number" title="25 people like Jose">25</span>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
      <p class="title">SCRT</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</li>
```

I need to grab content like `name` and `title`, `like`, etc.:

```
def find_page_data(url)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(html))
  data = [] 
  doc.css('.profile').each do |item|
    name= item.at_css("n fn").text
    like_no = item.at_css(".like-number").text
    title = item.css("p")[0].text
    data << [name,title,like_no]
  end
  data
end
```

I am getting data blank as `doc.css('.profile')` is returning a blank array because `class="profile "` is ending with a blank space, so I am unable to get that.

Comment: Are you sure the space is a problem? I tried it and it worked fine. It is possible that it is one of the other lines of code causing a problem. For example, `item.at_css("n fn")` will return nothing because there is no `n` or `fn` node.

Comment: Why can't you change your code to "class='profile'"?

Comment: Your conclusion is incorrect. Your data is blank due to some other reason. I can see at least one error: your name selector is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces inside `class` parameters are expected and work fine:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
<html>
  <body>
    <p class="foo ">found foo</p>
    <p class="foo bar">found bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.at('.foo').to_html # => "<p class=\"foo \">found foo</p>"
doc.search('.foo').to_html # => "<p class=\"foo \">found foo</p><p class=\"foo bar\">found bar</p>"
doc.at('.bar').to_html # => "<p class=\"foo bar\">found bar</p>"
```

Notice how Nokogiri found `.foo` in both the first two checks, as it should, and `.bar` in the last one.

All classes contain an embedded space.